# Вставить элемент из первого списка во второй, при этом не теряя значения из второго списка

Tags: python, массивы

Написал вот такой код, который ищет недостающий элемент в списке, и при обнаружении добавляет этот элемент в конец списка:

```
massive1 = ['a','b', 'c', 'd']
massive2 = ['b','e','d']
massive3 =[]
massive3 = massive1
for i in massive2:
    if i not in massive3:
      massive3.append(i)
print(*massive3)
```

Но хочу сделать так, чтобы он добавлял этот недостающий элемент перед тем значением, с которым произошло несовпадение при проверке, так, чтобы остальные элементы сдвигались вправо.
Пробовал с помощью функции .insert, но выдавало ошибку, поэтому прошу помощь

Comment: Во-первых ссылка `massive3` у вас указывает на массив `massive1`, вы точно этого хотели? Во-вторых непонятно, какое поведение вы ожидаете. Если элемент не нашёлся нигде в массиве, куда вы его хотите вставлять, на какую позицию? На позицию после того элемента, который ранее был найден, т.е. `'e'` нужно вставить после `'b'` получается (он был найден ранее)?

Comment: @CrazyElf Если нигде в массиве не обнаружен схожий элемент, то элемент который мы хотим вставить уходит просто в конец массива. А по поводу ссылки я хочу сначала заполнить `massive3` наиболее объёмным массивом, то есть `massive1` и потом сравнивать полученный массив с `massive2`

Comment: Ничего непонятно. Если добавлять в конец массива, то зачем тогда `хочу сделать так чтобы он добавлял этот недостающий элемент перед тем значением, с которым произошло несовпадение при проверке`. Какая вообще **реальная** задача?

Comment: @Ulcus_Molle То есть если элемент найден, то его всё-равно нужно вставлять в массив? Вы уж определитесь - добавляется элемент, который не найден, или который найден тоже добавляется (в какую позицию? опять непонятно)

Comment: @MBo Мы должны соединить два массива в один массив так, чтобы не было повторяющихся элементов и порядок обоих массивов был максимально сохранён. Так при объединении массивов `['a','b', 'c', 'd']` и `['b','e','d']` должен получится массив `['a','b', 'c', 'e', 'd']`

Comment: Почему "е" вставляется именно так,а не перед "c"? Возможно, чёткая формулировка критериев поможет решить задачу.

Comment: @Ulcus_Molle А, то есть фактически вам нужно сначала найти следующий элемент, который есть в массиве и вставить этот отсутствующий элемент перед ним.

Comment: @CrazyElf Да, это и нужно